# Embed JS in Apache FOP PDF (for print)

Tags: pdf-generation, apache-fop

I need to add to my apache FOP created PDF a javascript, that will prompt print window when opened in browser.
(Actually, maybe I don't need js, if there is a better option, but I don't know about any)

How can I do that?

Comment: While your intent is OK ... it what application will the PDF be opened ... always. Adobe? Chrome? Edge? One of the 50+ other PDF viewing applications? Many if not most of them do not support any form of scripting including Javascript inside the PDF to be executed. 

So your request is a dream that cannot be realized in all cases unless you have a totally controlled audience that you also need to specify.

Comment: Another way to ask the same question is ... please point all of us to a sample PDF link to be opened that does exactly what you want. If you can find one.

Comment: @KevinBrown hey. Application will be opened in browser, always. It's ann app that runs in shop in the browser, and that's the behaviour that client requires. I need to add this js and it has to work in firefox and chrome, I know both will support it, I just down know how to add this in Apache FOP